# push set of values for each object of json into different arrays

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

At the moment I have the following code, A JSON file, and with underscore I push the product ids of each look into one array, what I would like to do is push the product ids of each look into their own array, so I would have `productArray1`, `productArray2`, `productArray3` etc. How could I adapt this?

**JSON**

```
looks = [{
        "id": "look1",
        "products": ["hbeu50271385", "hbeu50274296", "hbeu50272359", "hbeu50272802"]
    }, {
        "id": "look2",
        "products": [
            "hbeu50274106", "hbeu50273647", "hbeu50274754", "hbeu50274063", "hbeu50274911", "hbeu50274106", "hbeu50240022", "hbeu50271944"
        ]
    }, {
        "id": "look3",
        "products": [
            "hbeu50272935", "hbeu50274426", "hbeu50271624", "hbeu50274762", "hbeu50275366", "hbeu50274433", "hbeu50262002", "hbeu50272364", "hbeu50272359"
        ]
    }
    .......
]
```

**JS (Underscore)**

```
var productArray = []
_.each(looks, function(look) {
  _.each(look.products, function(product) {
    productArray.push(product.replace(/_.*/, ''))
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but are you just asking how to create an array of arrays?

```
var productArrays = [];
_.each(looks, function(look) {
  var productArray = [];
  _.each(look.products, function(product) {
    productArray.push(product.replace(/_.*/, ''))
  })
  productArrays.push(productArray);
});
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/acam2rzo/

This code will result in a 2D Array like so:

```
[
  ["hbeu50271385"1: "hbeu50274296"2: "hbeu50272359"3: "hbeu50272802"],
  ["hbeu50274106"1: "hbeu50273647"2: "hbeu50274754"3: "hbeu50274063"4: "hbeu50274911"5: "hbeu50274106"6: "hbeu50240022"7: "hbeu50271944"length],
  ["hbeu50272935"1: "hbeu50274426"2: "hbeu50271624"3: "hbeu50274762"4: "hbeu50275366"5: "hbeu50274433"6: "hbeu50262002"7: "hbeu50272364"8: "hbeu50272359"]
];
```

Comment: I want an array with look1's product ids, an array with look 2's ids etc etc. so the array for look1 would have just these values: "hbeu50271385", "hbeu50274296", "hbeu50272359", "hbeu50272802"

Comment: so not an array of arrays, just a set of arrays.

Comment: A "set" is just a collection in which values don't repeat. Since you're only creating 1 array per product (as defined in the JSON) for this array-of-arrays, your outer array *would be* a set. Maybe I'm still half asleep, but I'm still not seeing how my above code snippet wouldn't return what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let's build a list of `[name, products]` pairs and then pass that list to [`_.object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object) to output an object having `productArrayn` as keys and the desired arrays of products as values :

```
var res = _.chain(looks).
    map(function(look) {
        return [
            "productArray" + look.id.substr(4),
            _.map(look.products, function(product) {
                return product.replace(/_.*/, '');
            })
        ];
    }).
    object().
    value();
```

would output

```
productArray1: ["hbeu50271385", "hbeu50274296", ...],
productArray2: ["hbeu50274106", "hbeu50273647", ...],
productArray3: ["hbeu50272935", "hbeu50274426", ...],
....
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/fkmtksz5/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, `productArrays` will contain each of your product arrays, using their IDs as keys e.g: `productArrays.look1` contains all of look1's products.

```
var productArrays = {};

_.each(looks, function (look) {
  productArrays[look.id] = [];

  _.each(look.products, function (product) {
    productArrays[look.id].push(product.replace(/_.*/, ''));
  });

});
```